# Single or Multiple IDs for same value but in different states/questions

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a lookup value "Unread". It is used here:
Mail can be read or unread. (So i have ID 10 = read and ID 11 = unread). Now in the UI I have display filters where i can sort message by predefined filters, one of these is 'Unread' So the question is: Are the IDs in both cases going to be 11 or do i create two separate values for Unread - one for the message state and one for the display sort?

The use of this data is 2 folds:
1) Reference its main action based on the FK lookup ID
2) Reporting: If i want to see how many users sorted using Unread filter for Unread mail, in which case can i get that number easily - by using two IDs (one for each question (message state and display sort) or one ID only?

Answer (score 1):

The status value of read/unread is a property of the message item, not of the GUI or the user.  The filter state selected by the user is a property of the user, not the message.

If it makes sense to you to have the same values used in these two similar, but independent code columns, then that is fine.

You need to store the message state as a column on the message (unless you want to track the history of message state, in which case it has to go into a child table of the message).  You need to store the current filter selection state for each user on your user table.  I can't imagine why you'd want to historize that so a single column on your user table should do the trick.

If unread in the message table is "11" and unread in the user table is also "11" then that's fine, but it's coincidental and you want to be careful about making any assumptions in your code about this.  When you start adding in other filter combinations the whole scheme could come crashing down on you unless you're committed to having matched pairs of attributes in your user/gui filter selection table and whatever message attributes line up with your filter options.

Comment: Well, if i use different then what about with lookup values for drop downs. Say the 'year' lookup for 2011. It can be birth_year and it can also be company_join_date. in both cases it is 2011. So i assume in this case it is the same ID even when the data is stored in different tables?

Comment: First, figure out who taught you to assign id numbers to years. Then hunt them down and poke them in the eye with your finger.

Comment: Using IDs for dates, as you are, is common in Data Warehouse type DBs and can be done in transactional ones too.  But is it worth it?  Maybe if you are using it to prevent user's text entry.  However if you do go down that path there is nothing wrong with having a lookup value (in this case 2011) referenced by ID in 2 different tables, with 2 different meanings.  The context provides the meaning.  Turn your question arround, if you write the value '2011' to your db in field A, is it ok to write '2011' into field B?  Even if they mean different things (e.g. birth_year and company_join_date)

Comment: To extend Karl's very good point, when you have an attribute that has a life outside of your business (e.g. the number of a year), you don't need to anonymize it with a meaningless key.  2011 will always mean the same thing in a date column, or if not for some reason then it will mean whatever it means within the context of the column in which the 2011 is found.  Being different columns doesn't make the data uncomparable.  Can you not ask the question who has been born since X joined the company?  Having the same data value in two places is never a guarantee that the data means the same thing.